# sftp public rsa key ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 14.04, sftp, 16.04

Why is there a different format when creating a public rsa key in Ubuntu 16.04 compared to Ubuntu 14.04?

Ubuntu 14.04

```
test@ubuntu:/etc/ssh$ ssh-keygen -lf ssh_host_rsa_key.pub 
2048 ad:e2:ec:56:c0:df:26:36:8a:a4:1e:64:8f:c6:84:4c  root@ubuntu (RSA)
```

Ubuntu 16.04

```
test@test-VirtualBox:/etc/ssh$ ssh-keygen -lf ssh_host_rsa_key.pub 
2048 SHA256:YWPFBWJYHxxy9FatUnzzsFiZ+QkSpWAKjAy3pZ2GL+Y root@test-VirtualBox (RSA)
```

Is it possible to get same format in 16.04 as in 14.04?

Comment: It seems that Ubuntu 16.04 created a public keygen with SHA256 as standard but I need to create it with MD5. Is it possible to somehow generate a key with MD5 instead of SHA256 in Ubuntu 16.04?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well looked around and found a answer

https://superuser.com/questions/929566/sha256-ssh-fingerprint-given-by-the-client-but-only-md5-fingerprint-known-for-se

It is still possible to create a md5 key with this command

```
ssh-keygen -lf ssh_host_rsa_key.pub -E md5
```

Comment: The format of the key is still the same, but the fingerprint have a new format.